# Adding foreach to a template engine

Tags: php

I am trying to add the foreach loop to this template I am working on but I keep getting thrown the error `Warning: preg_replace(): Parameter mismatch, pattern is a string while replacement is an array` I understand what the error is saying I just don't know how to fix it. Can anyone help?

here are the `preg_replace`'s

```
/* FOREACH Statement */
$content = preg_replace('/\{foreach (.*)\}/U', '<?php foreach ($1) { ?>', $content);
$content = preg_replace('/\{\/foreach\}/U', '<?php }; ?>', $content);
```

and here is the `.php` file where I created the variable

```
$names = array(
        'Name',
        'Name2',
        'Name3',
        'Name4'
    );

$template->assign('members', $names);
```

and here it is implemented on the page

```
<p>Here are some members of my family:</p>

{foreach ({members} as $member)}
    <p>$member</p>
{/foreach}
```

Comment: Please look at the [`preg_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) manual.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are after is `{foreach ($members as $member)}` in your template

Comment: the first preg_replace call is matching `{foreach ({members}` as opposed to `{foreach ({members} as $member)}` which is what I assume is intended.  You can change this behavior by dropping the ungreedy modifier off of the pattern (the tailing U).

Comment: That did not do anything it is still spitting out the same error. It is not accepting the array is the issue. I need to know how to change it so it does.

Comment: i assumed it would accept it because of the `(.*)` and the `($1)`